# Is most of the Star Wars galaxy colonized?

Tags: star-wars, space-colonization, planets

I watch all *Star Wars* TV shows and read all *Star Wars* literature. In these stories, characters go to tons and tons of new (relative to the audience) planets and it seems a majority of them have been settled and have a living presence on them. Why this is, can probably be attributed to terraforming being used on a ton of planets millennia ago, and the galaxy having had FTL travel for over 25,000 years prior. That's a lot of time. I know Wild Space is messily mapped and the Unknown Regions are, well, unknown, but is it safe to say the Inner, Mid and Outer Rims are mostly completely colonized by the time of *The Phantom Menace*?

Answer (score 2):

According to the *[Star Wars: Essential Atlas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas)* the **Core Region** is largely uncolonised (because it's mostly uninhabitable), the **Hub Worlds** were colonised during the early age of galactic exploration (tens of thousands of years ago), the **Colony Region** is *largely* colonised*(mainly by settlers from the inner worlds and miners looking to supply those worlds with vital resources), the **Expansion Region** is *mostly* colonised and the **Outer Rim** consists of a mix of colonised worlds and uncolonised (but largely inhabited) worlds.

> Do the math and you wind up with about 7.1 billion habitable stars
> in the known galaxy—that’s about 3.2 billion habitable star systems.
> We haven’t gotten everywhere yet — it’s estimated that **nearly a billion
> of those systems actually have someone living in them.** But most of
> those places are pretty lonely — if I’m remembering my census data
> correctly, about 69 million of those systems meet the population
> requirements for Imperial representation, and just 1.75 million
> planers are full member worlds.

In short, wherever you find a world that can support life, you'll find someone living there, whether that's '[a local](https://youtu.be/BisZQdr0nG4)', freebooting miners or homesteaders looking to make a life for themselves. Entirely uninhabited worlds are pretty much a rarity in the Sky River Galaxy, although things become a lot murkier in the Outer Rim and Wild Space.